# how to stop vue from loading images with native lazy loading?

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading

We're using VUE for SVG and not for images but for some reason, it loads them on demand. so my native lazy loading is not working. I tried removing VUE and it worked but we can't obviously do that.

So what are my alternatives here? Also, VUE is not in any way related to the images since it's only purpose is for our SVG which in its own is a separate entity.

I don't really want to add more script here hence me using the native lazy loading instead implemented by the browsers. (https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/)

We're running Laravel 5.8, PHP

Comment: same problem here. native lazy loading of images with loading="lazy" stops working when vue scripts are included in the page - images get automatically loaded by vue

Comment: created a ticket on github with detailed explanation of the issue and a possible workaround: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/6859

Comment: @schellmax thank you for that. I just gave up on this. Seems you're more persistent though :)